# how to add a list of names in a insert into?

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

On Oracle, I have a list of name such as 'a','b','c' and I would like to insert them in a table. The dimension of this list can change. so  cannot do it like :

```
insert all  
  into TEMP (name) values ('a') 
  into TEMP (name) values ('b') 
  into BBU (name) values ('b') 
  into BBU (name) values ('c') 
select * from TEMP;
```

How can I make the insert into more dynamic ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a list of names"? In what manner do you "have" the list? Is it in a table (and if so, in what form - as separate rows, one per name, or just as one long comma-separated string)? Is it a user input? Is it in a text file outside the database? "I have" is not very helpful.

Comment: I meant that I have a list of value given by another user under the following form :" 'a','b','c' "

Comment: So, your input is a single string, of the form `'a','b','c'`? And you need to split it first? How are you splitting it now - manually?

Comment: That is part of the question , how can I split it and then insert them ?

Comment: How to split a string: The question has been asked on this site at least 100 times. Google for "split comma-separated string", you will get many links to how it's done. After you split the string, the INSERT statement is trivial (you are surely able to write it yourself).

Comment: Is inserting into two tables (TEMP and BBU) part of the problem? If so, what are the rules for deciding which value goes in which table? If not, please **edit your question** so it accurately reflects the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `VARRAY` or a collection:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP ( name )
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ) );
```

Or use a delimited list and then [split it](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings) (there are multiple solutions for splitting delimited strings at that link but one is):

```
INSERT INTO TEMP ( name )
SELECT x.item.getStringVal()
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         ( '"a","b","c","d","e"' )
         COLUMNS item XMLTYPE PATH '.'
       ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PL/SQL instead. And loop through.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR myCur IS
SELECT name FROM myTable;
TYPE xTab IS TABLE OF myCur%ROWTYPE;
L_tab xTab;
BEGIN
OPEN myCur;
FETCH myCur INTO L_tab;
CLOSE myCur;
FORALL i IN 1..L_tab.COUNT
   INSERT INTO myTab2 (name) VALUES (L_tab(i).name);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Now if you are worried to exceed your tempspace (`redo logs`) coz the list is millions of records, then use limit:

```
DECLARE
myLimit NUMBER := 32000;
myFlag BOOLEAN := FALSE;
CURSOR myCur IS
SELECT name FROM myTable;
TYPE xTab IS TABLE OF myCur%ROWTYPE;
L_tab xTab;
BEGIN
OPEN myCur;
LOOP
FETCH myCur INTO L_tab LIMIT myLimit;
IF myCur%NOTFOUND
THEN
   IF L_tab.COUNT != 0
   THEN
      myFlag := TRUE;
   ELSE
      EXIT;
   END IF;
END IF;
FORALL i IN 1..L_tab.COUNT
   INSERT INTO myTab2 (name) VALUES (L_tab(i).name);
COMMIT;
EXIT WHEN myFlag = TRUE;
END LOOP;
CLOSE myCur;
END;
/
```

Comment: I don't think you have nearly enough information from the OP to decide that PL/SQL is the best answer. PL/SQL should only be used when plain SQL can't do the job.

Comment: Agreed, though it is just a suggestion, and it would work

Answer (score 0):

If your data is saved in some column of a given table, use this

```
insert into TEMP (name)
select name_column from given_table;
commit;
```

Comment: No the data are note saved in a given table